# A question from code in python's graph theory essays

Tags: python, if-statement, graph-theory, delimiter

The code is to determine a path between two nodes for directed graphs. [This](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) is the code:

```
def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return path
        if not graph.has_key(start):
            return None
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
                if newpath: return newpath
        return None
```

Being new to python, I two have small and trivial questions. I hope you don't mind it.

Q1. What does  `if newpath:` in the second last line of the code mean?

Q2. Does this code gives **all** possible paths in the directed graph?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: This checks whether the call of find_path actually returns something. See the language docs to find out what gets interpreted as true and what as false if the type of the term is not boolean to start with. (In this case, None evaluates to false).

Q2: No: this function gives exactly one path from start to end.

Comment: Thanks user507787. Can you tell which path would that be? Would that be the path possible from the first encountered value of the key?

Comment: Read up on Depth-First-Search and Breadth-First-Search on Wikipedia. The algorithm implemented by the code above is DFS, meaning that if you are given an ordering of traversal of edges at every node, it will find the path with an associated sequence (m0, m1, m2, ...) where we choose the mo-th edge at start etc in a way such that the sequence is smallest under lexicographical ordering.

Comment: user507787: If you have seen the link for that python essay page, then I want to ask does the code given there to find all possible paths is also implemented using DFS? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Try to visualize what the program is doing: If it arrives at a node x and checks out one neighbour x*, it goes deeper, i.e. checks out the neighbours of x*. Only after all of them are dealt with does it return and look at other neighbours of x. This is what's meant by DFS. For BFS, you would look at all neighbours of x first before going another level 'down'. If you want an exercise, try to modify the find_path routine to implement BFS instead.